# Add comment link is too close to Flag link

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, localization, post-menu

Due to the long words and the number of links on the *modified by* the post author post and if there are no comments yet, the link to add a comment ("Добавить комментарий") is placed very close to the *Flag* link ("Тревога"), [e.g.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/495343/176217):

> [image]

Even for non-logged users:

> [image]

Could the distance between the links please be increased? This could reduce the number of misclicks.