# How can I determine if this is a bug or feature-request for design tagged question?

Tags: discussion, tags, design, bug-reports, feature-request-process

Some design issues are based completely on personal opinion. In some other situations, they feel like an edge case, like this one: [Add comment link is too close to Flag link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389096/339911)

Should this be tagged as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)? I'm not sure, hence I added both. 
But maybe can I choose more right based on some metrics?

So how can I decide if this is (and the further posts tagged [design](/questions/tagged/design)) a bug report or a feature request for a design-related thing?

Comment: You can use the [tag:support] tag to ask if something is a bug or not - in fact, [tag:possible-bug] is a synonym of that tag.

Comment: @Sonic I faced sometimes ago an interesting situation when I created BR, but dev argues that my BR is a FR actually. But I think that it is a BR yet. Although IIRC that old Q was about localization not design. So the clear metrics would help us to decide what it is.

Comment: Well, if it's something that used to work in the past and doesn't work in the same way anymore, it's a bug, unless that change was made on purpose. Otherwise most likely a feature request.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard the question in the interpretation of "used to work". What do you think about linked post? Is it BR of FR, and why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand usually a bug would get priority, so it does matter.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ the linked one is bug, as there is vertical margin between elements all around, and there it's missing. Classic design bug, usually due to switching or forgetting CSS classes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand of course, it's up to the experienced users and/or mods viewing the question to retag as needed. Most people will consider almost everything as "bug" of some sort, so when it's not, it's not their fault if they're new, but it falls upon us to notice and put correct tag.

Answer (score 7):

To be honest, tags are entirely arbitrary. In a properly functioning meta - it’s entirely fine for a staff member to re-tag a post or even edit it if they feel it has merit.

The only 'advantage' of a bug tag is - it’s an actual *obvious* bug that a MSE mod can replicate, we could in theory retag it. Whether a design issue is a bug is... kind of subjective unless it obviously breaks the normal user flow of the site.

Alternately a feature request that's currently in the roadmap might have priority. Still a retag is trivial, and not a big deal.

If it’s 'ugly', and specific to certain situations, accommodating those situations feels more like an [FR](https://blog.trello.com/3-ways-to-manage-feature-requests) than a bug report to me, especially if the site is generally still usable.