# The anonymous "Post your answer" button gets squashed

Tags: bug, design, answers, anonymous

Across all SE sites when I visit a question without being signed in and scroll down to the bottom, there is an option to submit an answer as a guest, but I don't think the button should be wrapped (the width of the button should fit the unbroken text). Some might say this is a feature, but I think it's a pretty bad one.

[image: incorrect wrapping]

The text wrapping can be fixed by adding `flex-shrink: 0` to the button, but the padding and spacing still needs some fixing.

Comment: I'd say this is a request for improvement, but the current situation is not wrong. Calling this a bug seems a bit too much.

Comment: [Duplicate on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424838/missing-margin-around-post-your-answer-button)

Comment: It's a (relatively recent) regression, @Mast; that makes it a bug absent evidence to the contrary (e.g., staff saying that this cramped design is intentional).

Comment: @Mast which primary tag would be more relevant?

Comment: Well, if it's a regression it may be a bug. If not, it's more a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Mast see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389114/339911) how to choose the tag.